# Draw horizontal lines like open and close brackets

Tags: rules

I need to draw two horizontal lines which look like open and close brackets:

```
 ___________________________________________________________________
|                                                                   |

  Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text
  Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text
  Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text    

|___________________________________________________________________|
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please give us an MWE to play around with. Why not a real bracket? What about the vertical lines? Also needed? And where exactly should they be aligned?

Comment: Thanks, As I said, I need horizontal lines whose edges look like brackets, exactly like above. They should fill text width.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here a quick and dirty (and not greatly coded) solution.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\newcommand{\downbracket}{\par\noindent\rlap{\rule[-2ex]{.4pt}{2ex}}\rule{\linewidth}{.4pt}\llap{\rule[-2ex]{.4pt}{2ex}}\par}
\newcommand{\upbracket}{\par\noindent\rlap{\rule{.4pt}{2ex}}\rule{\linewidth}{.4pt}\llap{\rule{.4pt}{2ex}}\par}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\downbracket

\lipsum[2-3]

\upbracket

\lipsum[4]

\end{document}
```

Of course you can adjust the parameters to suit your needs.

Answer (score 6):

You can use [`tcolorbox`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tcolorbox); page breaks are allowed:

[image]

The code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newcommand\InitialLines{
    \draw[] 
      ([yshift=-10pt]frame.north west) -- 
      (frame.north west) -- 
      (frame.north east) --
      ([yshift=-10pt]frame.north east);
}
\newcommand\FinalLines{
    \draw[] 
      ([yshift=10pt]frame.south west) -- 
      (frame.south west) -- 
      (frame.south east) --
      ([yshift=10pt]frame.south east);
}

\newtcolorbox{textbracket}{
  breakable,
  empty,
  before=\vskip10pt,
  after=\vskip10pt,
  overlay unbroken={\InitialLines\FinalLines},
  overlay first={\InitialLines},
  overlay last={\FinalLines}
}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[4]
\begin{textbracket}
\lipsum[4]
\end{textbracket}
\lipsum[4]
\begin{textbracket}
\lipsum[1-6]
\end{textbracket}

\end{document}
```

If you want the text inside to have a width equal to the regular `\textwidth`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newcommand\InitialLines{
    \draw[] 
      ([yshift=-10pt]frame.north west) -- 
      (frame.north west) -- 
      (frame.north east) --
      ([yshift=-10pt]frame.north east);
}
\newcommand\FinalLines{
    \draw[] 
      ([yshift=10pt]frame.south west) -- 
      (frame.south west) -- 
      (frame.south east) --
      ([yshift=10pt]frame.south east);
}

\newtcolorbox{textbracket}{
  breakable,
  empty,
  oversize,
  left=0pt,
  right=0pt,
  before=\vskip10pt,
  after=\vskip10pt,
  overlay unbroken={\InitialLines\FinalLines},
  overlay first={\InitialLines},
  overlay last={\FinalLines}
}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[4]
\begin{textbracket}
\lipsum[4]
\end{textbracket}
\lipsum[4]
\begin{textbracket}
\lipsum[1-6]
\end{textbracket}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I propose this simple macro, `\hbrackets`, which uses the `\under/overbrackets` commands, from `mathtools`. Note it is easy to customise the line thickness, and the height of the vertical part (they're optional arguments to these commands), but don't break across pages:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\newcommand\hbrackets[1]{\medskip\par\noindent$\underbracket[0.6pt]{\overbracket[0.6pt]{
\parbox{\linewidth}{\rule{0pt}{1.8ex}#1\vskip 0.2ex}}}_{}$\par}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\hbrackets{\lipsum[2-3]}

\lipsum[4]

\end{document}
```

[image]